# Use IdentiyServer or not for external login provider only web application with asp.net core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am building a web application with

- Asp.net Core 2.0 Web API
- AngularJS 4+
- SQL Server
- User signup/login only through Google/Facebook/LinkedIn. I will save user info like name and email I receive from them into SQL db table. I do not have a plan to offer manual registration on my website with email and password. I do not want to maintain user credentials, forget the password, securing user passwords and all nitty-gritty around that.

As of now, there is no plan to build a mobile app. I am learning .Net Core and stumble upon IdentityServer4 as a recommended way to provide identity in asp.net core applications. I went through all docs, example and tried out few sample application. I think I am clear how configuration and workflow of identityserver.

My questions are

- Is it worth employing IdentityServer4 in my architecture since my identity is external provider only? I was thinking about using default Asp.net Identity with.AddCookie(), .AddGoogle() and .AddJwtBearer() to retrieve the cookie from Google/Facebook/LinkedIn, use AddGoogle AddFacebook AddLinkedIn middleware to handle callback, extract claimprincipal and set Jwt token for Angular JS app to use in its XMLHttp request.
- What benefits do I get outsourcing this work to IdentityServer4 besides identity in one place best practice?

I appreciate your tiny or big feedback on this.

Comment: Think the close votes are a bit harsh here. It's a valid question on a subject (auth) that's never as simple as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

IdentityServer is great for handling many clients that access many protected resources. You seem to have one client (the so called AngularJS 4+ app) and one resource, the Asp.net Core 2.0 Web API.

A point of clarity is that you have no need for ASP.NET Identity and all those middlewares for Google, LinkedIn, etc. If your client is truly an Angular javascript application, then it does not need a server side component like ASP.NET Core- it is simply a browser application. You can use a javascript library like oidc-client and configure your external authentication providers according to their own needs. You will receive an id_token and/or access_token to store in browser and utlimately pass to your Api Resource.

Speaking of your Api Resource, this application can validate directly with the token issuer, be it Google or Facebook or whoever.

So with this setup: (a) a browser app (Angular), (b) a server WebApi (ASP.NET CORE), and (c) and an identity/access control service (Google, Facebook, etc.) you certainly do not need any additional applications that run ASP.NET Identity or IdentityServer4. Seems like it would be easier without them.

If your Angular app is actually in an ASP.NET MVC, then the same is true.

If your Angular app and your WebApi are all part on one ASP.NET project then the same is true and all you need is an identity provider to return an id_token.

Comment: Thanks for an insightful answer. My client is 100% Angular 4+ and server side is only Asp.net Core Web API only. Angular app is outside of MVC project/solution but ultimately it builds into wwwroot folder of web api. If I receive token from Google/Facebook into browser html and save it into browser and not post to server side, how will i create/update user data into database?

Comment: you will send the token to server in your http requests. It will contain the identity information for your database.